# How to filter Bitfinex API ws2 stream data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, lodash

I try to filter specific data from WS stream with this code:

```
bws.on('open', () => {
  console.log('WS open')
bws.subscribeTrades('BTCUSD')

bws.on('trade', (pair, msg) => {
    var trades = msg.map(function (msg) {
        return {
            trade_id: msg.ID,
            time: msg.MTS,
            size: Math.abs(msg.AMOUNT),
            price: msg.PRICE,
            side: msg.AMOUNT > 0 ? 'buy' : 'sell'
        }
    })
    console.log('Trades:\n', trades)
})
```

I get undefined data:

```
WS open
Trades:
[ {
<..> 
{ 
     trade_id: 43477863,
     time: 1500037112000,
     size: 0.01,
     price: 2259.7,
     side: 'buy' 
} ]
Trades:
 [ { trade_id: undefined,
     time: undefined,
      size: NaN,
      price: undefined,
      side: 'sell' 
 }, { 
      trade_id: 43478179,
      time: 1500037170000,
      size: 0.35702096,
      price: 2259.9,
      side: 'sell' 
} ]
Trades:
[ { trade_id: undefined,
    time: undefined,
    size: NaN,
    price: undefined,
    side: 'sell' 
}, { 
    trade_id: 43478179,
    time: 1500037170000,
    size: 0.35702096,
    price: 2259.9,
    side: 'sell' 
} ]
```

It is streaming

```
[{ID:,MTS:,AMOUNT:,PRICE},{ID:,MTS:,AMOUNT:,PRICE:}]
```

in the first block, then updates with

```
['te',{ID:,MTS:,AMOUNT:,PRICE:}]
```

and

```
['tu', {ID:,MTS:,AMOUNT:,PRICE:}]
```

I suppose I get 'undefined' when these updates occur.  How do I manage that? 
It is already parsed JSON via API.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution:

```
var wstrades = []
bws.on('open', () => {
  console.log('WS open')
bws.subscribeTrades('BTCUSD')
bws.on('close', () => {
  console.log('WS close')
})
bws.on('trade', (pair, data) => {
  wstrades.push( {
    trade_id: data[1].ID,
    time: data[1].MTS,
    size: Math.abs(data[1].AMOUNT),
    price: data[1].PRICE,
    side: data[1].AMOUNT > 0 ? 'buy' : 'sell'
  })
  var t = wstrades
  var trades = t.map(function (trade) {
    return (trade)
  })
  console.log('Trades:\n', trades)
})
```

Though an output have duplicates due to 'te' and 'tu' updates:

```
Trades:
 [ { trade_id: 43683909,
    time: 1500097172000,
    size: 1,
    price: 2109.8,
    side: 'buy' },
  { trade_id: 43683913,
    time: 1500097178000,
    size: 0.0075,
    price: 2109.8,
    side: 'buy' },
  { trade_id: 43683914,
    time: 1500097178000,
    size: 0.9925,
    price: 2110,
    side: 'buy' },
  { trade_id: 43683913,
    time: 1500097178000,
    size: 0.0075,
    price: 2109.8,
    side: 'buy' } ]
```

No 'undefined'. But not able to filter specific arrays...Still open.